# seaborn displot: Non-comparabale density estimations

Tags: python, seaborn, kernel-density

I have a problem creating a seaborn.displot() to compare the densities of two unequally sized groups:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotnine as p9

n_x = 100
n_y = 1000

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, n_x)
y = np.random.normal(1, 1, n_y)

values = np.concatenate((x, y))
groups = ["x"]*n_x + ["y"]*n_y

dat = pd.DataFrame({"values":values, 
                    "groups":groups})

print(dat.head())

sns.displot(data=dat, 
            x="values", 
            kind="kde",
            hue="groups")
plt.show()
```

results in

[seaborn example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SASl.png)

The two density estimators obviously don't cover the same area, which they should by theory (edit for clarification: by "area", I'm referring to the integral, not to the location. I'd expect two similar curves with a shift.)

This can't be observed for pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde and plotnine:

```
dat.loc[dat.groups == "x","values"].plot.kde()
dat.loc[dat.groups == "y","values"].plot.kde()
plt.show()
```

gives

[pyplot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAuaw.png)

and

```
(
    p9.ggplot(dat, 
              p9.aes(x="values",
                    fill="groups")) +
    p9.geom_density(alpha=.5)
)
```

gives

[plotnine example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRFOx.png)

Could someone give me a hint what's going on with the seaborn version? Did I miss a parameter or something..?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I think you want to set [`common_norm=False`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)

Comment: Well, I think I actually misunderstood that very parameter (and my expectation would swap the default, but that's of course only that, "my expectation"...). 
Thank you for the quick and helpful response!